# Python randomly choose corresponding elements from 2 lists

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of numbers X and Y, and I want to choose 10 random elements from each, given as 2 lists of 10 numbers.

For example: if X is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and Y is `[10,20,30,40,50]` and I want 2 elements, I want `([1,3], [10,30])`

This is my use case:

```
lin_reg_all(X, Y):
    ...

lin_reg_sample(X, Y):
    X_sample, Y_sample = ?
    lin_reg_all(X_sample, Y_sample)
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip the two lists together, and then randomly sample that list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
c = list(zip(a, b))
d = random.sample(c, 2)
```

Now, zip *those* tuples.

```
e = list(zip(*d))
```

Demonstrated:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> c = list(zip(a, b))
>>> d = random.sample(c, 2)
>>> list(zip(*d))
[(4, 5), (40, 50)]
>>> d = random.sample(c, 2)
>>> list(zip(*d))
[(4, 1), (40, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use `np.random.choice`

```
import numpy as np
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10,20,30,40,50]

y_1 = list(np.random.choice(y, 2))
x_1 = [x[y.index(i)] for i in y_1]

x_1,y_1
```

output, the above code will give two elements randomly.

```
([4, 5], [40, 50])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get corresponding items from both lists, you want to use random indexes rather than random selections from each list.

```
N = min(len(X), len(Y))
indexes = random.choices(range(N), k=10)
X_sample = [X[i] for i in indexes]
Y_sample = [Y[i] for i in indexes]
```